# How to Get Value and Do Validation of Input inside *ngFor Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a Form (multiple Input fields) inside `ngFor` and i want to get values and validate them and add them to Users array to send it back to API.

```
  <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div *ngFor="let user of users">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }" />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && f.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.lastName.errors }" />
          <div *ngIf="submitted && f.lastName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f.lastName.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  users=[ 
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3}
  ]


  registerForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; };

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(this.registerForm.value) // here i am getting value from last edited index.
  }
}
```

Edit:
[Stackblitz Exmple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxqbjq)

Comment: Do you want to create form filed based on users array?

Comment: Yes, I want to create form on Users array. and add input value to that array so i can send to Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create array of FormGroup using users array.

**Try this:**

**component.ts**

```
 this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userDetails: this.formBuilder.array(this.users.map(item=>{
       return this.createItem(item) 
      })),
  });
```

Since userDetails control is array of formGroup you don't need to use users array in html.

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formArrayName="userDetails" *ngFor="let item of registerForm.get('userDetails').controls; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control"  />
                <div *ngIf="submitted && registerForm.controls['userDetails'].invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div>First Name is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control"  />
                <div *ngIf="submitted && registerForm.controls['userDetails'].invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div>Last Name is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2p8szc)

Comment: you need't enclosed the formArray inside a FormGroup, you can use directly the formArray

Comment: Yes since he already grouped formarray inside from group i have used similar approach

Answer (score 0):

you cant use a simple FormControl, for array values. formControl is only for a single value, so only the last edited value will be attached to them, you need to use 
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray for that

Comment: How can i do this? that's the real question. i have tried many examples but nothing worked for me.

Comment: As per your Suggestion i tried it with `FormArray`  but still it only get last edited values. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxqbjq

Comment: you need some modifications there, first remove users *ngFor and leave only formArray ngFor and second call as many createItems() as many users you have, you need one forrmGroup for each one, and third remove formGroupName and add formGroup="item" (the third option is extra, but anyway do it you don't need index there )